# push and pull not ordering the elements correctly in Bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the following code, I want to swap positions of `Small` and `Large` HTML element when resolution is `sm` or `xs`. When I add `pull-` and `push-`, the layout goes berserk! What is the correct way to use `push-` and `pull-`?

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
<!-- div class="col-xs-6  pull-xs-12 col-md-3 -- This doesn't work> 
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><h5>Small</h5></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">sm1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">sm2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">sm3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><h5>Medium</h5></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">md1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">md2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">md3</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><h5>Large</h5></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">lg1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">lg2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">lg3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
<!-- div class="col-xs-6  push-xs-12 col-md-3 -- This doesn't work> 
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><h5>X-Large</h5></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">xl1</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">xl2</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">xl3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div>I am free</div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the newest version, Bootstrap 4 beta 2, you should use the `order` classes.

They support breakpoints, so you could use something like `order-1 order-sm-2` as a class on your column(s).

You can read more about them [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering).

*For Bootstrap 4 alpha:*

If you have a layout like `col-8` and `col-4` and want to reorder these, you'll use these classes: `col-8 push-4` and `col-4 pull-8`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that. I am learning how to use `pull-` and `push-`. How do I solve the problem with `push-` and `pull-`?

Comment: Push and pull classes are removed from the newest version. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system-1). What version are you using?

Comment: Well, I'd recommend that you upgrade to the beta, as it has a bunch of enhancements (like better order system using the `order` class), but [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system-1)'s the docs for push and pull. I'll do an example soon.

Comment: Tried `order` but couldn't get it to work. In fact, I am not getting the layout correctly at all now. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386044/incorrect-ordering-of-columns-in-bootstrap4-beta